# running jmeter recorded script but data no getting updated on database or UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jmeter-4.0

I am using Jmeter in order to test a web application. The issue i am facing is that when i am running the recorded script. I cannot see the data getting added in the database or in the UI of the application.

I recorded a script in which i added the data but when i run it, the response code is 200 and i have added regular expression extractors wherever needed. But still with no luck.

While looking at the View Result Tree, I can even see the Response that data is getting added but not on UI or DB.

Comment: (1) Are you sure your endpoints (URL) are correct between JMeter and manual check ?

Comment: (2) Can you provide more information, more precisely input (JMeter script ?) and output. It's hard to figure out what happening w/o concrete data.

Comment: @LoganMzz where shal i send you the script???i am just inputting a data on my project's website...i can see the "Response" tab showing me the data but not the DB or UI

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you have recorded a JMeter script which is supposed to create new data into your application. Then rerun it and run seems ok ; but you don't see any modification into your application ?

Comment: @LoganMzz yes that's correct..nothing is happening in the application..am i missing something?

Comment: As JMeter as be used for long time now (including myself), it's sure you have miss something ... So first typical error is to record from one server and trying to rerun against another one but forgetting to add/update variable for the base URL

Comment: @LoganMzz can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: When developing JMeter scripts, it's recommended to [add variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables), especially for things related to environment (i.e. base URL with protocol, hostname, port and context path). It would be easier if can share JMeter script using Gist for example.

Comment: @LoganMzz Can you provide me your mail address where i can share my script with you?

Comment: (1) I don't provide e-mail address on public site. (2) It's a public place if you send me information in private, no other one would be able to help you.

Comment: I know that but i am unable to provide you with any info over here...how shall i provide you my script?

Comment: Does your site use cookies? Does your site use other authentication as token?

Comment: Ya the site uses cookies

Answer (score 0):

If your website is using cookies to handle user sessions, you must add to your Test plan [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to save and send cookie in HTTP requests.

> it stores and sends cookies just like a web browser. If you have an HTTP Request and the response contains a cookie, the Cookie Manager automatically stores that cookie and will use it for all future requests to that particular web site.

Comment: thanks for the info..this issue has been resolved...there was some issue in the script only